# Could not find method androidExtensions()

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension, gradle-experimental

**I want to use the features of kotlin @Parcelize,** 
I have `apply the plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` on gradle, and I added

```
androidExtensions { 
    experimental = true 
}
```

but errors continue to appear.this error message :

```
Error:(28, 0) Could not find method androidExtensions() for arguments [build_8di01fmxa4d18k9q0yy3fdd20$_run_closure2@27f46852] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
<a href="openFile:F:\BELAJAR\ANDROID\AndroidStudioProjects\KADE\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Use the latest version of Kotlin (>= v1.1.51)
- Use the latest version of Kotlin Android Extensions in your app module,
  so your `build.gradle` may look like:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
   androidExtensions {
     experimental = true
   } 
}

dependencies {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Using of Kotlin `parcelize` you have to follow these steps:

1- Add this line into your Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'
```

2-Enable android Extensions in your Gradle too :

```
 androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
```

That's it. But be aware that you have added 
`apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` in your gradle too if you didn't before.

Comment: The plugin has since been updated to `'kotlin-android-extensions'` as mentioned by @SML, i.e. You no longer need following                                                                 
    `apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'`

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in build file
  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

Answer (score 0):

1. Add these plugins up to step 2.

   - apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   - apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
   - apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
2. 

```
android {
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}
```